# Move the configuration by features

Tags: 8, layout-builder

There is a module in the D8 core - Layout Builder. The functionality is enough for my needs. I need initiate the settings by a profile and also have possibilities to move configurations from stage to stage. If layout builder is configured for every content type it is possible to move the settings by the configuration or features. In my case the layout builder is configured for every node. So this is the content entity. I tried a module default_content to move content to the configuration. But it saved an empty field. It was related with a serialization problem. [Serialized node does not contain layout data](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2987281)
Is it possible to attach the layout builder to a configurable entity?

Comment: You can use any method described here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management, although I would prefer drush if you want to move configuration on a regular basis. But I think the question is too broad, since this is not specific to a module, because all configuration is treated the same.

Comment: Partly we can. I need add a specification. The layout builder settings is save in every node.

Comment: It looks like there's an existing issue for it: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2942975

Comment: Yes, it is possible. To fix json structure apply this patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2942975#comment-13315805 See my comment #63 for details.